# Consoled into Nexus 5596 and can't SSH or Ping directly attached servers - No route to host

Tags: cisco, cisco-ios, cisco-nexus-5k

How can I SSH to my Servers from Cisco IOS. My only current access to router is via console port.

Comment: Can you share your configuration?

Comment: Is your Nexus a L2-only switch and routing is performed elsewhere?  Also be careful when posting configs and sanitize passwords, etc.

Comment: With the Nexus, you have to be careful with the built in management port, as it is in a seperate VRF.  So if that is where the Nexus has the Layer 3 interface to these servers, you just need to specific the VRF when pinging/etc.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Ah, been there, done that!

Which vrf are you pinging from. By default the IP is on the MGMT vrf. So you do a ping sourcing it from the mgmt vrf.

Also that mgmt network has to be routable to where the IPs of these servers you are pinging are sitting. Otherwise, it wont ping , even if it is on the same switch.